# Crop and Save images with Transparent Background

Tags: images, gimp, image-editing

I have several hundred images that I need to crop and save as PNG without saving the background color (maintain transparency).  The files are in PNG format and I have been using Gimp 2 for Windows as well as Linux to perform the tasks manually.

However, I am curious if there is a way to crop all of the images from position 0,0 and 360x515 pixils either from a command line or a batch process?

Comment: Just to add to the answer below, GIMP has a [batch mode](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Imagemagick's` `convert` command to do this from the command line:

```
% convert 404.jpg -crop 250x250+0+0 404-new.jpg
```

Where 250x250 is the size of the region I want to crop and the beginning X & Y coordinates are (0,0).

#### Before

[image: before]

#### After

[image: after]

You could call it in a shell script like so:

```
for file in `ls *.jpg`; do
  baseName = $(echo $file | cut -d"." -f1);
  convert $file -crop 360x515+0+0 ${file}-new.jpg;
done
```

See this link for more details: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/

Comment: That's everything except one thing.  The images have a transparent background.  Is there an extra switch to leave the background transparent.  In gimp I have to uncheck "Save Background Color" to achieve this.

Comment: Try adding the argument `-transparent white`. Change white to whatever color is your background. Look at `man convert` for more info.

Comment: As it was, the image was already transparent and without any command, IM retained the transparency.  Thank you.